# Getting 'else' without 'if' errors, don't know why

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

This is in Java and I'm using TextWrangler. I'm getting several errors including 'else' without 'if' errors and can't figure out why. I also had to take out" public class Tax {
    public static void main(String[]args) {" because it was telling me they weren't coded properly. Some examples of the errors I've been getting include:

```
Tax.java:85: error: 'else' without 'if'
        else(taxable <= 186475)

Tax.java:85: error: ';' expected
        else(taxable <= 186475)
                               ^

Tax.java:85: error: not a statement
        else(taxable <= 186475)
            ^

import java.util.Scanner;


    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    double tax;

    System.out.print("Please enter filing status: ");
    int status = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter taxable income: ");
    double taxable = input.nextDouble();

    if(status == 0){
        if(taxable <= 8350)
            tax = taxable * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
        else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351)
            taxable = taxable - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        else if(82250 >= taxable && taxable >= 33951)
            taxable = taxable - 33950 - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .25 + 33950 * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        else if(171550 >= taxable && taxable >= 82251)
            taxable = taxable - 82250 - 33950 - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .28 + 82250 * .25 + 33950 * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        else if(372950 >= taxable && taxable >= 171551)
            taxable = taxable - 171550 - 82250 - 33950 - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .33 + 171550 * .28 + 82250 * .25 + 33950 * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        else(taxable <= 372951)
            taxable = taxable - 372950 - 171550 - 82250 - 33950 - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .35 + 372950 * .33 + 171550 * .28 + 82250 * .25 + 33950 * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        }
```

Comment: Seems you are a beginner. Habituate to use `{}`.

Comment: I actually used those before but fore some reason it caused even more problems to pop up, but now those problems aren't popping up. Still have the other two errors popping up, but the original problem is gone.

Comment: Don't forget the word "if" in this line: "else(taxable <= 372951)" - you need to say "else if" (or, just "else" without a condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put braces around your 'then' clauses. For example:

```
if(taxable <= 8350) {
        tax = taxable * .10;
        System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
}
else  .....
```

Answer (score 3):

Always enclose ***all*** blocks of code in curly braces, especially if starting out, including all if blocks, all loops, all control structures.

Your faulty indentation is fooling you making you think that the if block contains 3 lines of code when it only contains one line.

You see this:

```
    if (taxable <= 8350)
        tax = taxable * .10;
        System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
    else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351)
        taxable = taxable - 8350;
        tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
        System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
```

Is really equivalent to this:

```
    if (taxable <= 8350) {
        tax = taxable * .10;
    }

    System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    

    // you've got a hanging else here
    else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351) {
        taxable = taxable - 8350;
    }

    tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
    System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);

    // and more hanging else's below...
```

So change it to this:

```
    if (taxable <= 8350) {
        tax = taxable * .10;
        System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
    }  else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351) {
        taxable = taxable - 8350;
        tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
        System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
    } //.... and continue similarly throughout your program
```

Comment: Thanks, was able to fix the problem of 'else' without 'if' error, but I still have these guys popping up:

Comment: `java:102: error: not a statement
   else(taxable <= 186475){
       ^
Tax.java:102: error: ';' expected
   else(taxable <= 186475){
                          ^`

Answer (score 1):

If you have more then one statement for if-else then use braces around then. It better to use braces always.

Form [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed. The following example, BlockDemo, illustrates the use of blocks.

Write it like following:

```
   if(status == 0){
        if(taxable <= 8350){
            tax = taxable * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
         }
        else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351){
            taxable = taxable - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
         }

 ....
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the curly braces for the if.

```
if(taxable <= 8350){
            tax = taxable * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);    
        }else if(33950 >= taxable && taxable >= 8351){
            taxable = taxable - 8350;
            tax = taxable * .15 + 8350 * .10;
            System.out.println("Tax is " + tax);
        }
```

Otherwise, it's like only the first line is inside the if

Answer (score 0):

Because your if statements are not bracketed off with {} 's

This means that only the next line counts under that if statement. The following lines are executed outside of an if statement and then the "else" statement is placed without an if before it.

Answer (score 0):

If the body of IF or ELSE spans more than one statement, you need to use curly braces.

Comment: Technically, it's more than one *statement*.